# Displaying the values of a nested array list in JSF data table

Tags: jsf, multidimensional-array, datatable

Its been quite some time since i have started developing web pages using JSF but i am still learning most of the stuff. Now I have an interesting question

When I have the values those to be displayed in a data table in the ArrayList and I am adding those ArrayList objects in another array list , so now how will i be able to display them in a data table.

I am doing this since , i need my table to be so dynamic so that i dont know how many columns will i be getting in the result set to be displayed in the page, hece i cannot have a Bean obj for storing my variable values. So i have decided to have something like

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>

ArrayList<String> - Values for Each row
```

Does this have a solution that can be provided int he jsf page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use either plain HTML with a nested `<ui:repeat>`

```html
<table>
    <ui:repeat value="#{bean.rows}" var="row">
        <tr>
            <ui:repeat value="#{row}" var="column">
                <td>#{column}</td>
            </ui:repeat>
        </tr>
    </ui:repeat>
</table>
```

or grab a 3rd party component library which has sort of a `<x:columns>` tag like [PrimeFaces](http://primefaces.org) with [`<p:columns>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableDynamicColumns.jsf) and [Tomahawk](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk) with [`<t:columns>`](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk-project/tomahawk20/tagdoc/t_columns.html).

```html
<p:dataTable value="#{bean.rows}" var="row">
    <p:columns value="#{row}" var="column">
        #{column}
    </p:columns>
</p:dataTable>
```

Either way, you can even keep the columns in a separate list.

Comment: Now will i be able to insert a checkbox in the columns so that for those rows the user selects i can take the action