# Primefaces data table sorting and aligning

Tags: primefaces

I want to build the web site footer dynamically from the Arraylist. I am using primefaces as UI.

The green image below is the one i want using primefaces so far i got the data table like image below (in blue and white).

This is the primefaces code i am using. Can someone give me an idea how i can have the primefaces data table or data list to build the footer like green image below.
In the footer2List i have "category" which as the header like (social media, community) and the "description" as the child data.

Thanks in advance.

```
 <p:dataTable var="fot" value="#{footer2MB.footer2List}" sortBy="#{fot.category}">
    <p:columnGroup type="header">
        <p:row>
            <p:column colspan="2">
                <b><h:outputText value="#{fot.category}"/></b>
            </p:column>
        </p:row>                
    </p:columnGroup>

    <p:column headerText="fotId" colspan="7">
        <h:outputLink  target="_new#{fot.url}" value="#{request.contextPath}#{fot.url}">
        <h:outputText value = "#{fot.description}" />
         </h:outputLink>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

[image: this is what i have]

[image: This is how i want it to look like]
[image]

Comment: Why are you using a data table for that part? And what is the relation with the first image

Comment: Just use  two nested ui:repeats and some CSS

Comment: I used the data table to see if i can build it like green image with simple sort and columnGroup before i start using my custom code. The relationship is the table is three columns "Category" will have the header and the "Description"  will have child data and even have column "Parent Id" where the child data will have the header id. Idea is to keep in one table instead of two.

Comment: Noone mentioned two tables

Comment: i am using one table not two. The primfaces UI data table get the List from managed bean. All the data are in one list.

Comment: YOU mentioned two tables in your previous comment like we suggested that.  If the bullits belowb the description are formatted in one variable, you only need one loop,but your problem is unclear then. Your titles is for sure unclear in relation to the question content

Comment: Added data base table screen shot in question above. Is there a simple way to accomplish this using Primefaces with out writing custom code in UI.

Comment: Yes there is... use the datatable as shown in the showcase

Comment: The showcase does not have the sample i need unless i am looking at wrong url. The showcase examples are simple display from table no sort or group that i need.

Comment: then you should start from scratch and be clear what you want. The images you added last is plain datatable

Comment: i think we are beating the dead horse here ....! my original question was how i will make the plain data table to look like one in the green image using primeface

Comment: Then please continue doing that if you like, I won't. **Your question is unclear as it stands (at least for me)**. Cheers.

Comment: thanks for trying really appreciate that. i will try with primfaces data table with sort and group by if it does not work i will write custom code.

Comment: Back to my first comment. Honestly, I feel like you are trying to put a round peg in a square hole. Why do you need a datatable to display something like what is shown in green. The (in JPA a normal parent child relation in grouping can (should) be done one the dao (the query and direct processing -> Sort on ), the sorting requirement is totally invisible. The amount of 'custom' code you need to write is almost 0 when using two `ui:repeat` with jpa...

Comment: The plan is to make one data base (JPA) call from one table have them cached and the front end should do all the sorting and order the table should  like in green image. If i need to added more data all i need is add a row in  a table and don't have to touch the code in website at all. FYI : it does not have to be a data table any primfaces data grid is fine for me.

Comment: The front-end doing sorting is only for user interactions, this sort of sorting (whatever sorting that may be since you dont mention any specifically)  should be in the service/business layer. And 'Any primefaces datagrid'.... PLEASE drop the idea a PF component (or any other serious component framework) will have something for this. Do it as mentioned in the answer. Most simple and elegant way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really feels like you are trying to put a round peg in a square hole when you are trying to (ab)use a datatable for this. The amount of css you would need to format it like you have shown is disproportionatly high compared to using two nested `ui:repeats`.

You seem to have the parent-child relation in one table. So if you have not already done so, start with modeling your own JPA entity like done in "[JPA mapping for Parent-Child with same class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8584764/jpa-mapping-for-parent-child-with-same-class)" (if you are not using jpa, you need to write some code but that is also rather simple and straight forward)

Write *JQL* that retrieves the toplevel records: `select r from MyRecord r where parent_id is null`.

Then in pseudocode do:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{myBean.rootRecords}" var="rootRecord">
    <h3>#{rootRecord.title}</h3>
    <ul>
    <ui:repeat value="#{rootRecord.children}" var="child">
        <li>#{child.title}</li>
    </ui:repeat>
    </ul>
</ui:repeat>
```

Which is sort of what is done here: [Displaying the values of a nested array list in JSF data table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9460357/displaying-the-values-of-a-nested-array-list-in-jsf-data-table)

One optimization you could look at is the either lazy or eager loading of the children in JPA. Another would be the use of `p:cache`... [Primefaces p:cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36007272/primefaces-pcache)

All plain and simple without the hassle of a datatable.

(off-topic: I am almost 100% sure you already spent more time trying to (ab)use the datatable and creating the question and discussing it with me than it would have cost if you did it directly in the way described in this answer ;-))

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply ... I am using JPA and I tried this approach already and i got error "The class 'java.lang.String' does not have the property 'title' " even though it exists in child. Thanks for the very detail answer and i am going to start looking at from JPA to see if i had it correct ... especially the one table parent child relation ship. I will let you know.

Comment: @skrk: so the first thing tpu did was post the error in searchengine like https://www.google.com/search?q=%22The+class+%27java.lang.String%27+does+not+have+the+property+%27%22 and got a hit that suggested to switch to using datatable? I get different results

Comment: this works like a charm saves lot of time thank you very much.